# How to sleep/delay background worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an Windows phone Application. I need send an request to web service every one minute without interrupt the front end. So I create an `BackgroundWorker`. If I get data I have to run four of the methods on different condition. In the every method contains a sound file(length 5 seconds). When I run the program If I invoke two of these methods sounds was mixed. So I try to sleep that background worker thread. But I could not find the sleep method for `CurrentThread` instance. When I use `Thread.Sleep(5000);` I unable to access front end until thread wake-up(5 seconds). How to sleep the background thread? or how to make delay until the first sound finish?

Thanks In Advance.

One of the method below.

```
public void NotificationForNewjob()
{
    Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Assets/NewJob.wav");
    SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    effect.Play();
    //bool x = Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground;
    //Thread.Sleep(5000);
    //Thread.CurrentThread.
    //Setting.IsDownload = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you invoking `NotificationForNewJob` on a background thread? Because we don't see it in your code.

Comment: yes within the above method when I check Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground property x become true.

Comment: If you are using Windows Phone, you should use the async await stuff instead of threading. `Thread.Sleep` is really really expensive. Use `await Task.Delay` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Debug Background Task check this refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj542416.aspx